# Is my reputation on meta linked to the site?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that my reputation on Salesforce meta is the same as the one on the actual site. On Stackoverflow I have seperate reputation on meta and on the site. Is this because this is still in beta? My badges are not "copied".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [FAQ for the meta site](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

## What is reputation?

You must have at least 5 reputation on the main website to participate on Salesforce Meta - Stack Exchange.

Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

(Please note that offensive penalties, if levied by the community through spam or offensive votes on your posts here, will affect your reputation on the main website.)

Amass enough reputation points on the main site and Salesforce - Stack Exchange will allow you to do more things:

- 15 - Vote up
- 15 - Flag for moderator attention
- 50 - Leave comments†
- 100 - Edit community wiki posts
- 125 - Vote down
- 150 - Create new tags
- 200 - Reduced advertising
- 200 - Retag questions
- 250 - Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
- 500 - Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
- 750 - Show total up and down vote counts
- 1000 - Edit other people’s posts
- 2000 - Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

† you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep.

At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That is very much intentional. We don’t run Salesforce - Stack Exchange. The community does.

Comment: Right, thanks. I did skip through the FAQ, but I must've missed it...

Comment: You can track privileges and learn more about each one here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges